Can I use methods from other classes inside a java POJO class?
I have a Java POJO class with some data members and getters and setters.
Class TestClass {

private member1, member2, member3; //assuming I have 3 members
// Getters and setters are declared

@Override 
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class TestClass{\n");
    sb.append(member1 == null ? "null" : member1.toString.replace("\n", "\n    ");
    sb.append(member2 == null ? "null" : member2.toString.replace("\n", "\n    ");
    sb.append(member2 == null ? "null" : member2.toString.replace("\n", "\n    ");
    sb.append("}");
   return sb.toString();
}

The logic written in toString has to be duplicated in many of my POJO classes. Can I write the logic in a separate utility class as a static method like:
public static String toStringMethod(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
    }

and replace the code in the toString of my POJO classes?

Yes you can, and yes, it is a good practice. But I am not so sure how you would be able to avoid duplicate code for every object that should be very specific.
About the format, can you use a different format? Like the one your IDE generates? Or maybe use Lombok @ToString annotation?

If you just want to replace the line breaks with the following, then you can. Improve it, the return value of toStringMethod should use replaceAll instead of replace.
If you want every POJO's toString to call toStringMethod, unfortunately it's not possible because POJO.toString calls toStringMethod, and you also see that toStringMethod calls POJO.toString, causing stack overflow due to cyclic method dependencies. Generally speaking, toString can be automatically generated using IDEA or annotated using LomBok's @ AKS class

Inside the toStringMethod, I am just passing an object which is a data member in the pojo. I want to run the operation member.toString().replace("\n", "\n    "); on all pojo class'  overridden toString method.

It is feasible to format member variables by calling the toStringMethod method. Just a reminder, the replace ("\ n", "\ n") you are using here can only replace the first line break. If you need to replace all line breaks, you need to use the replaceAll method.
